# in Ubuntu 18.04, how to resize windows by keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, window

In the Ubuntu 16.04, I very appreciated resizing windows by Ctrl+Alt+Num shortcuts; e.g. Ctrl+Alt+7 resized a window into the top left quarter of the current screen. In the Ubuntu 18.04, only Ctrl+Alt+5 and Ctrl+Alt+0 works. I see a possibility to 'Add Custom Shortcut'. What commands should I use for the other Ctrl+Alt+Num shortcuts according to the Ubuntu 16.04? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in Ubuntu 18.04 using the GNOME extension Put Windows.

Version 16.04 uses the Unity desktop and works in a different way.

[image]

If you are uncertain as to how to install GNOME extensions you can refer to [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) easy to follow guide

When in use, left <kbd>Win</kbd> + 7,9,5,1,3 keys on the number pad will move the window to top left, top right, center, bottom left, bottom right respectively.

Comment: I'd like to retain Ctrl+Alt+5 for maximizing and Ctrl+Alt+0 for minimizing. I have set all the other shortcuts that I am used to and they work.

Comment: In the Put Windows Main settings, switching 'Move to center maximizes and restores initial window size' on fulfills the last of my wishes.

Comment: In the Put Windows,setting 'Extension settings' ...'Width & Height'...'Center Width & Height' to 50% for all the three first cases results to the behavior I very liked in the Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: 'Put Windows' can be invoked directly in the 'Ubuntu Software'.

Answer (score 0):

They [Quarter Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4857/quarter-windows/?c=143856) extension for GNOME.